# How to download all the images from a website in ubuntu where the image width is greater than 602px?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, ubuntu-18.04

How to download all the images from a website in ubuntu where the image width is greater than 602px?  I mean I don't want to download thumbnail or resized pics only want to download original pixels of images.

Give me the example code for this page " https://hdqwalls.com/category/funny-wallpapers "

**Example:**

Small thumbnail [ 300x200 px]:
https://images.hdqwalls.com/wallpapers/thumb/smile-cry-box-09.jpg

Big thumbnail [ 602x339  px]: https://images.hdqwalls.com/wallpapers/bthumb/smile-cry-box-09.jpg

Original image [ full pixel ]: https://images.hdqwalls.com/wallpapers/smile-cry-box-09.jpg

*I know a code but I'm not sure about it.*

```
wget -i `wget -qO- https://wall.alphacoders.com/by_sub_category.php?id=169002&name=Model+Wallpapers | sed -n '/<img/s/.*src="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p' | awk '{gsub("thumb-350-", "");print}'`
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details: What exactly means "images ... which are greater than 500px"? What website are you referring to? Your code extracts data from the HTML code of a specific web page. There might be information about image sizes in the HTML code, e.g. because it might scale an image to a specific size, but this is not related to the actual size of an image file. Your code assumes that removing `thumb-350-` from an image URL leads to the normal size image corresponding to a thumbnail. This highly depends on the specific implementation of a web site or page.

Comment: Please check the updated question.

Comment: I think it is difficult to implement a check of the image size as mentioned in the question, but it is possible to extract all thumbnail imge URLs and construct the full size image URLs according to the example shown in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The script below works for the specific web page https://hdqwalls.com/category/funny-wallpapers
with the assumption that the URL to the full size image can be derived from the thumbnail image URL as shown in the example in the question.

It does not check the image size but it simply tries to download all constructed image URLs that are supposed to be the full size images corresponding to the thumbnail images.
(It is not possible to check the image size without downloading the file first.)

The escaped line breaks are for better readability only.

```
wget -O- https://hdqwalls.com/category/funny-wallpapers | \
  grep -o "<img src='https://images.hdqwalls.com/wallpapers/thumb/[^.]*.jpg'" | \
  sed -e "s/[^']*'//" -e "s/'.*//" -e "s#/thumb/#/#" | \
  wget -i-
```

Short explanation:

- first `wget` to send the HTML code of the page to the pipe
- `grep` to extract the thumbnail image tags from the HTML code
- `sed` to extract the pure thumbnail URL from the HTML tag and to remove the subdirectory `/thumb/` to derive the full size image URL from the thumbnail URL
- second `wget` to download the URLs received as standard input

Of course there are other ways to achieve the same result.

If you want to use the script for other web pages you might have to adapt the `grep` pattern and the `sed` substitution command as necessary.